# Wordpress Fatal error: Call to undefined function wpum_get_option()

Tags: php, wordpress

So i was asked to help some people out who didn't have any experience with Wordpress. First thing that they needed help with was updating wordpress.
I was able to update wordpress to the latest version, however when updating the plug ins it crashed at the last one.

I can't get into the dashboard anymore at all and the [website](http://svhumanistiek.nl/) Isn't working anymore either. 
Of course this has to happen when you're trying to help someone and not when doing it for your own website.

Anyway, i'm at a loss, so many people saying so many fixes but i'm not sure which one i need because a lot of people get different fatal errors it seems.
[image] Above i posted a picture of the error i got in my screen after trying to update it. I'm checking to see if i can get the account for the hosting so i can get into the host files. As of now i don't have acces to them.

I hope someone can help me out, thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm assuming that because you're asking the question that you didn't take a full backup before doing the updates? If not, your best bet is to get access to those files and (if you can) the database and try [disabling all the plugins](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/wordpress/disable-a-wordpress-plugin/). Enable them one by one until you find the one that is broken.  Good luck - and make sure you back up next time :)

Comment: Thanks, i already found the broken one by googling the WPUM. So now all i need to do is wait for them to get me the log in to the ftp for the host files :)

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need access to the hosting provider. If that's the only error that you have, the easiest thing you can do is to access the `plugins` folder via FTP (or via the hosting provider's file manager) and change the name of the `wpum-recaptcha` folder temporarily. This will prevent WP from loading that plugin, and should allow you to get in the dashboard at least.

At that point, you will have to either find an updated, working version of that plugin or remove it entirely.

Comment: Thank you so much, i have asked them for acces to the hostfiles. As of yet i don't have that yet. But as soon as i do I'll try this fix!
Really hope it works, will let you know!